# Impressão cupom não fiscal PHP

Tags: php, laravel

Olá, gostaria de saber se é possível imprimir cupom não fiscal via PHP?

Se sim, como poderia fazer essa implementação? Eu uso o Laravel 5.5

Answer (score 0):

Acho que usando só CSS e um pouquinho de javascript dá para solucionar o seu problema.

CSS

```
#areaDeImpressao {
    display: none;
}

@media print {
   * {
       display: none;
    }
    #areaDeImpressao {
       display: block;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="areaDeImpressao">
    <h1>Imprimir isto</h1>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="window.print()" value="Imprimir" />
```